# WordPress, I have no direct access to uploaded images

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have Linux Host and WordPress based weblog. I create post and add my images and then publish my post.
Everything is okay and when I see my post by direct link there is no problem and I can see my images inside post.

My problem is when I open direct link of an image (like: http://www.kamalan.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/01.jpg) server show me following error (while I can see image when I open its post).

any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after 6 hours I found the solution.
To those people who have same problem the solutionis:

I assume you have Linux host.

- Go to root of your host (`/public_html`) and open `.htaccess` file.
- Remove this line: `RewriteRule .*.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]` (you can comment it out by adding "#" before this command)
- save file.

Comment: Hi Thanks, for accepting own answers we need to wait a day or two, if i'm not mistaken. I still need to wait 5 more hours :(

Comment: Just wanted to let you know your answer from 5 years ago was exactly what I was looking for. This fixed a Facebook scraping error that I've been trying to debug for weeks.